# How can I avoid an infinite loop in my meteor router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, minimongo

I'm building an online store in meteor where customers can customize products in the store. I have setup a client-only collection called `Inventory` which stores all the product data and is updated accordingly in response to user input. Once the user is ready to checkout, I dump the product data into a client & server side collection called `ShoppingCart`. I want to allow users to go back and revise their edits on the product in `Inventory` so I setup my router to `$set` data from the `ShoppingCart` into `Inventory` if it finds a match:

```
Router.route '/:_type/:_id', ->
  Session.set "inCart", false
  @render @params._type, 
    data: =>
      storedItem = ShoppingCart.findOne {
        userId: Meteor.userId(), 
        image: @params._id
      }
      if storedItem?
        delete storedItem._id
        Inventory.update {image: @params._id}, {
          $set: storedItem
        }
      Inventory.findOne image: @params._id
```

EDIT: This seems to cause my router method to get stuck in an infinite loop whenever data in `Inventory` changes. Is there any way to avoid this issue? Is there a better way of handling this kind of data altogether that I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MAJOR CAVEAT** - I don't do CoffeeScript, so this is what I can gather having put your code through a compiler.

I think the problem is that the data function is reactive, and you're updating *and* returning an item from the Inventory collection within it. Every time the route runs, unless there is no `storedItem`, it's going to invalidate a computation on which it itself depends and thus rerun again immediately (and subsequently do the same again, etc...).

As a general rule, I think it's a very bad idea indeed to be updating a collection from within a data function - if you have to do this within the route function, consider the `onRun`, or `onBeforeAction` hooks for the update.

Final thing, just because I don't understand: why do you need to dump the item from the ShoppingCart back into Inventory?  Shouldn't it already be there, unless the user has started a new session?

Comment: The idea was to dump it so that the data would be there even when a new session is started, but clearly my approach was misguided. To accomplish that I think the best way is to use the same (persistent) collection everywhere instead of separate ones for different application states. What do you think?